# Parsing JSON object with AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

I am basically trying to write and read a simple object.

Writing:
`AsyncStorage.setItem('@Test', JSON.stringify(newStudent))`
Reading:
`console.log(JSON.parse(AsyncStorage.getItem('@Test')))`
But im getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1".

I Also tried
`console.log(AsyncStorage.getItem('@Test').ID)`
But im getting "Undefined".

How can I parse the object?

Comment: that is because either the item stored is empty or it is not a valid json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can get your information from AsyncStorage

### First:

```
const retriveData = async () => {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@Test");
    return JSON.parse(value)
}
```

Then you can simply call the function and catch the value in a variable

```
var test = retrieveData();
```

### Second:

If you do not want to use an async function.
You can create a hook that stores thaat will store the value of the variable and then update the value like so:

```
const [testValue, setTestValue] = useState(null);
AsyncStorage.getItem("@Test").then((value) => { setTestValue(value) });
```

Make sure that you are importing AsyncStorage this way:

```
import {AsyncStorage} from "react-native";
```

And not this way:

```
import AsyncStorage from "react-native";
```

If you need additional information about AsyncStorage look at the docs [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage).

Comment: AsynStorage package is deprecated from react-native. It's now part of the react-native-community.